# Writing files to Android 8.1.0 and above?

Tags: java, android, cordova, debugging

I am currently debugging an application and I am having a bug show between different android versions.

My app pulls an image from a database and stores it locally on the phone. On android phones 8.0.0 and below - the function works fine the image is saved to the phone and the User can view the file using DocumentViewer. Here is a log of it working:

```
-01-23 09:28:16.787 845-1170/REDACTED W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to PGEasyFile.getFromUrl blocked the main thread for 312ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
2019-01-23 09:28:16.794 845-1170/REDACTED D/DocumentViewer: Plugin called
2019-01-23 09:28:16.800 3809-6713/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 2898018304, maxLowBytes : 524288000
2019-01-23 09:28:16.809 845-1170/REDACTED D/DocumentViewer: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/REDACTED/cache/REF1062/3-blackadder.jpg
```

However when using android devices on 8.1.0 and above, when the user clicks on the image link - the file shows the loading circle and just hangs. It does not save the image file to the device or allow the user to view it: LogCat below: -

```
2019-01-23 09:39:53.121 32384-32384/? D/database location: /data/user/0/REDACTED/databases/database.db
2019-01-23 09:39:53.213 32173-32173/REDACTED I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(310)] "Error in Success callbackId: CVData390338918 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (310)
2019-01-23 09:39:53.229 32173-32173/REDACTED I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(51153)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/app-all.js (51153)
2019-01-23 09:39:53.296 32384-32384/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-01-23 09:39:53.341 32384-32384/? D/background sync: Logs found 1
2019-01-23 09:39:53.392 32384-32384/? I/SyncService: Completed service @ 1606891142
2019-01-23 09:39:53.394 794-4845/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 31897:android.process.media/u0a14 (adj 906): empty #17
2019-01-23 09:39:53.395 794-811/? W/zygote64: kill(-31897, 9) failed: No such process
2019-01-23 09:39:53.404 32173-32178/REDACTED I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=96KB
2019-01-23 09:39:53.405 32173-32178/REDACTED I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=114KB, data=71KB
2019-01-23 09:39:53.424 794-811/? W/zygote64: kill(-31897, 9) failed: No such process
2019-01-23 09:39:53.445 794-811/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) ActivityManager identical 1 line
2019-01-23 09:39:53.453 794-811/? W/zygote64: kill(-31897, 9) failed: No such process
2019-01-23 09:39:53.453 794-811/? I/zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10014 pid 31897 in 57ms
2019-01-23 09:39:54.022 32384-32384/REDACTED:remote V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 6 from 1 (600%)
2019-01-23 09:39:54.058 32384-32384/REDACTED:remote V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 2002 from 1 (200200%)
2019-01-23 09:39:54.832 32173-32178/REDACTED I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=114KB, data=75KB
2019-01-23 09:39:54.834 32173-32178/REDACTED I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=114KB, data=75KB
2019-01-23 09:39:54.834 32173-32178/REDACTED I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2019-01-23 09:39:54.971 578-961/? E/QC-QMI: linux_qmi_qmux_io_wake_lock: Err in writing wakelock=qmuxd_port_wl_0, error [1:Operation not permitted]
2019-01-23 09:39:54.972 578-961/? E/QC-QMI: linux_qmi_qmux_io_wake_unlock: Err in writing wakelock=qmuxd_port_wl_0, error [1:Operation not permitted]
2019-01-23 09:39:56.149 4270-4270/? I/GeofencerStateMachine: sendNewTransitions called.
2019-01-23 09:39:56.178 794-4839/? I/WifiService: getConnectionInfo uid=10018
2019-01-23 09:39:56.183 4270-31866/? I/GCoreUlr: Successfully inserted 1 locations
2019-01-23 09:39:57.512 794-1776/? I/nanohub: osLog: [AR_CHRE] still: 93
2019-01-23 09:39:57.514 794-1776/? I/nanohub: osLog: [AR_CHRE] ON => IDLE
2019-01-23 09:39:57.971 578-961/? E/QC-QMI: linux_qmi_qmux_io_wake_lock: Err in writing wakelock=qmuxd_port_wl_0, error [1:Operation not permitted]
2019-01-23 09:39:57.972 578-961/? E/QC-QMI: linux_qmi_qmux_io_wake_unlock: Err in writing wakelock=qmuxd_port_wl_0, error [1:Operation not permitted]
2019-01-23 09:40:00.060 19108-32409/? D/EventNotificationJob: Running EventNotificationJob, isDetail=true
2019-01-23 09:40:00.084 19108-32409/? D/EventNotificationJob:   finished processing events.
2019-01-23 09:40:01.460 19108-19300/? D/ClClient: Not sending keepalive.  Current connection state=STOPPED
```

I have looked at a view things currently as i was trying to narrow down the issue:-

1. First thing i looked at was Android TargetSDK was quite low (22) I increased this to 28.0.3 and still had the issue
2. After almost two days of reading I believe it could be an issue with permissions. The app requests:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

However it does this only in the ActivityManifest - I thought it could be an issue where the permissions request needs to be trigged at Runtime every time the user clicks an image due to security changes in Android 8.1.0 and above.

Am i heading in the right direction or can anyone else see something that I may have missed or what angle to best approach this?

Thanks

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has to be requested at runtime

Comment: How can i do this without, been racking my brains to get it to request without a button press?

Comment: Okay, I managed to get the request to come up at runtime at the start of the app loading. I get a little Toast message saying request permission success and when i check my app permissions they are all toggle true. However i can still not load the image.